# private upload folders for each user with CKFINDER

Tags: php, ckfinder

I would like to have ckfinder upload files in a private folder based on user_id. Is there any way to accomplish this? How can i call the config.php file to change the settings dynamically for each `ckeditor.replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

solved this using a session var in the config.php

Comment: Could you please explain more?